# Forge Viewer fails to dispaly PDF's

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using the sample C# SDK for using the Forge Derivative service and viewer. I've been successful with using any document but not with PDF. All the PDF's I've tried, translated successfully but it gives the following error when attempting to view.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) three.min.css

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'paperUnits' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just bumped into this myself. Please try with ViewingApplication object for initialization instead of basic viewer. The way shown in Basic Viewer requires additional configuration values from the manifest. 
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/basic-application/

Comment: Thank you, did not realize it needed additional values, i'll move to using the viewingapplication