# F2D streaming broken by non-streaming unzip error in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am testing viewing documents in the Forge Viewer after downloading the Bubble's locally. I've been successful up to this point with most formats but am having trouble with PDF's.

I was able to use the extractor project https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io with some modifications to get the PDF to extract. Investigating the downloaded files, they look to be correct.

However, when I go to load this file into the viewer I get the following error.

F2D streaming broken by non-streaming unzip!

Any details on what this means and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you initialize your viewer via the `Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication`? There are some configurations set up by the `Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication` for viewing PDFs.

Comment: I did not, we would like to initialize the viewer without using the Viewing Application. Is there any documentation on what configuration needs set up so that we can do it ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no formal documentation to set viewer up for viewing PDFs.

Current [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163705/forge-viewer-fails-to-dispaly-pdfs) is pointing to initialize your viewer with the `Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication`. It will obtain additional configuration values from the manifest for viewing PDFs. You can still retrieving the viewer instance via the `Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication.prototype.getCurrentViewer()`.

Here is the tutorial for the `Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication`:
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/basic-application/

Comment: I don't have a manifest to give the ViewingApplication though, I want to use this offline with downloaded files and want to pass the f2d file path directly into the viewer.loadmodel method. If I try to do this with the ViewingApplication loadDocument it throws invalid character exceptions. Also if try to use getCurrentViewer before loadDocument it returns null so I can't use the base viewer instance to load my model either in this case.

Comment: Manifest could be retrieved via the `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/manifest`, but it's not for offline usage. `ViewingApplication.getCurrentViewer ` cannot be used before calling `ViewingApplication.selectItem` and `ViewingApplication.selectItem`should be called inside `ViewingApplication.loadDocument`. If you want to call it before `ViewingApplication.loadDocument`, you should use `ViewingApplication.getViewer` instead. Here is the documentation https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewingapplication/.

Comment: Because there is no much formal supports and resources for the offline usage, I advise you to load your PDFs from the Forge Model Derivative service and initialize viewer with the `Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication`.