# Autodesk forge viewer pdf error

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am struggling to view a pdf in the forge viewer. All other drawings .rvt .dwg .dxf .nwd are showing without any issue.

Initially I received a error

> Cannot read property 'loadFromZip' of undefined

Have managed to evade this by adding "loadOptions" into the modeloptions I send through to the viewer. But now I get a error 6 back from the viewer which is a server error. Please if someone could advise what to do.

```
loadModel() {
    var initialViewable = viewables[indexViewable];
    var svfUrl = lmvDoc.getViewablePath(initialViewable);
    var modelOptions = {
        sharedPropertyDbPath: lmvDoc.getPropertyDbPath(),
        loadOptions: {}
    };
    viewer.loadModel(
        svfUrl,
        modelOptions,
        this.onLoadModelSuccess,
        this.onLoadModelError
    );
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ViewingApplication` rather than `Viewer3D` or `GuiViewer3D` to initialize your viewer to view PDF files since there are some additional configuration values for PDF set up by the `ViewingApplication` automatically.

Also refer to:
[Forge Viewer fails to dispaly PDF's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163705/forge-viewer-fails-to-dispaly-pdfs)

=== Example for passing configs to `Viewer` instance via `ViewingApplication` ===

```
//--- Method 1:
var viewerConfigs = {
    extensions: ['MyAwesomeExtension'],
    extOpts: {
        MyAwesomeExtension: {
             buttonColor: 'red'
        }
    }
};
var viewerApp = new Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication('MyViewerDiv');
viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D, viewerConfigs);

// In the constructor of the MyAwesomeExtension
class MyAwesomeExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
  constructor( viewer, options ) {
    super( viewer, options );

    // your options here
    const opts = options.extOpts.MyAwesomeExtension;
  }
}

//--- Method 2:
// After model was loadded,
var viewer = viewerApp.getCurrentViewer();
var extOpts = {
   opt1: true
};
viewer.loadExtension( 'Autodesk.ADN.MyExtension', extOpts );
```

For more details, please refer:

- https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/extensions/
- https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/basic-application/

Comment: Thank you @Eason Kang, will detect when dealing with pdfs to switch. Because we need the Viewer3D to pass options through to our extensions.

Comment: I added some examples for passing extension options to viewer while initializing it via `ViewingApplication`.